# Reference problem in C# for IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, reference

Code:

```
public static IQueryable GetAllBy_HesapAdiFirmaAdiCariNo_Turu_bypage_short(string filter, string tip, int page_size, int page_index, string sortcolumn, bool sortdirection)
{
    //bool tip: 0-tümü, 1-son kullanici, 2-bayi, 3- tedarikçi
    VeriyazDBDataContext db = new VeriyazDBDataContext(); db.Connection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
    var cariKayitlari = DAL.DAOCari.SelectAll();
    var kayitlar = (from rows in cariKayitlari
                    where rows.HESAPADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) ||
                        (rows.CARITURU == "Bireysel" ? rows.B_ADSOYAD.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower()) : 
                                                        rows.K_FIRMAADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())) ||
                        (rows.CARITURU == "Bireysel" ?
                        rows.B_ADSOYAD.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToUpper()) :
                        rows.K_FIRMAADI.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToUpper())) ||                                   
                        rows.ID.ToString().Contains(filter)
                    select rows);

    switch (tip)
    {
        case ("Tümü"):
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
        case ("Son Kullanici"):
        {
            kayitlar = kayitlar.Where(rows => rows.SONKULLANICI == true);
            break;
        }
        case ("Bayi"):
        {
            kayitlar = kayitlar.Where(rows => rows.BAYI == true);
            break;
        }
        case ("Tedarikçi"):
        {
            kayitlar = kayitlar.Where(rows => rows.TEDARIKCI == true);
            break;
        }
    }

    var kayitlar2 = from rows in kayitlar
                    select new
                    {
                        HESAPNO = rows.ID,
                        HESAPADI = rows.HESAPADI,
                        CARIADI = (rows.CARITURU == "Bireysel" ? rows.B_ADSOYAD : rows.K_FIRMAADI)
                        //BAKIYE= "",
                        //PARABIRIMI = rows.LISTEPARABIRIMI
                    };

    if (sortcolumn != "")
    {
        if (sortdirection)
            kayitlar2 = kayitlar2.Order(sortcolumn, SortDirection.Ascending).AsQueryable();
        else
            kayitlar2 = kayitlar2.Order(sortcolumn, SortDirection.Descending).AsQueryable();
    }

    return kayitlar2.Skip(page_size * (page_index)).Take(page_size);
}
```

I was calling this method from two different `System.Web.UI.Page` class in the below method

1. CariHesaplar
2. YeniBilet.

```
private void cari_paging_button_yenile()
{
    Button_CariIleri.Enabled = true;
    Button_CariGeri.Enabled = true;

    if (CariPageIndex == 0)
        Button_CariGeri.Enabled = false;
    string tumu = "Tümü";

    if (DAL.DAOCari.GetAllBy_HesapAdiFirmaAdiCariNo_Turu_bypage_short(TextBox_CariArama.Text, tumu, CariPageSize, CariPageIndex + 1, CariSortColumn, CariSortDirection).Count() == 0)//problem occured in this row
        Button_CariIleri.Enabled = false;
}
```

Problem: When I call `GetAllBy_HesapAdiFirmaAdiCariNo_Turu_bypage_short` in CariHesaplar I could get the count in the if statement in `cari_paging_button_yenile()`.However, in YeniBilet when I try to get the Count() I was getting

> Error 19  'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for
>   'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\yigit\Desktop\PROTicari
>   (11.04.2011)\UI\MusteriDestek\YeniBilet.aspx.cs   257 17  UI

I tried many things to solve this but nothing worked.Afterwards, I thought it could be a missing `using` statement on the beginning of the page.I checked both of the classes  `using`s only different was `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` but they both had `using System.Linq;` so I thought it couldn't be the problem.But then I wrote `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` on YeniBilet which was giving the error, too and error disappeared.

My question is why is `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` reference is not added when a page already has `using System.Linq;` isn't `Linq.Dynamic` like a subset of `Linq`?Why do I have to add it's reference again?

Comment: using directives are not adding a reference to anything. They are telling the compiler that you want to use a short hand for certain types. E.g. using System.Collections.Generic makes it possible to use the short hand IEnumerable<T> instead of the fully qualified name System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>. You add references to assemblies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Count()` does not exist for `IQueryable`, but does for `IQueryable<TSource>`. Except in System.Linq.Dynamic*, but System.Linq.Dynamic is not part of the Base Class Library and you will always have to add a reference to it (if you compiled it into a DLL) or use the namespace (if you included Dynamic.cs in your project). Its not a subset of Linq in the BCL. And to reinforce what everyone has stated, using a namespace uses *that* namespace only (its top-level). It is the design of the C# language and enforced by the compiler.

*Now deprecated in favour of [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

Comment: Thank you that was really illuminating.

Comment: Aha!!  That kept me going for about an hour.

Answer (score 2):

> isn't Linq.Dynamic like a subset of Linq?Why do I have to add it's reference again?

Well that would be the same as asking why do I need to add `System.Foo;` if I am already adding `using System;`. After all `Foo` is also a subset of `System`. It is the way namespaces work in C#, nested namespaces are not added when you add a parent namespace with a using directive.

You could argue that why doesn't the code file template add by default `System.Linq.Dynamic`. It would be in most cases unecessary as  `System.Linq.Dynamic` is a specialized use of the *Language Integrated Query* feature, which enables you to build dynamic queries.

Concerning there error you are getting, if you check MSDN, `IQueryable.Count` extension method *is* part of `System.Linq` so I am not sure how adding `System.Linq.Dynamic` solved your problem. [Queryable.Count Method (IQueryable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851.aspx)

Comment: So you are saying Linq does not have the  extensions Linq.Dynamic has?

Comment: "Concerning there error you are getting, if you check MSDN, IQueryable.Count extension method is part of System.Linq so I am not sure how adding System.Linq.Dynamic solved your problem. Queryable.Count Method (IQueryable)" I am not sure about that too but that was the solution.I tripple checked it.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why is using System.Linq.Dynamic; reference is not
>   added when a page already has using System.Linq; isn't Linq.Dynamic
>   like a subset of Linq?Why do I have to add it's reference again?

This is by design in C# the way you're talking about usings is the way imports work in java. In C# there's no `using System.Linq.*;`

Are you sure you're not using `IQueryable.Count` instead of `IQueryable.Count()`?

Comment: Yes I am sure about using Count(), thanks for the java-like explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `count` method is an extension method. Extension method requires the namespace in which they are defined to be imported with `using`

Comment: JohnnyCageWins: "...but they both had using System.Linq;"